# Flutter web has got stuck on white screen

Tags: flutter

My web app was working perfectly without any problem. But today when I tried to run the app, it got stuck in the startup screen. I tried running the upgrade, I ran `flutter clean and flutter pub get`, and checked some solutions from the web but none of them seemed to work. Can anyone help me? What's happening?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "XXXX",
        appId: "XXXX",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXX",
        projectId: "XXXX"),
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

//flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'HitchRide Admin',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null
            ? const GhanaUsersPage()
            : const Login());
  }
}
```

**This is my web app index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="hitchride_admin">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <title>hitchride_admin</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXX",
  appId: "XXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "XXXXXX"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. The app used to run well. The issue started today. Is there a solution to this?